# Selecting an Elementor template using WordPress REST api

Tags: wordpress, elementor

To select a template through the Wordpress REST api you normally assign the 'template' key a value. However, you don't appear to be able to select specific Elementor templates the same way. That is to say, the error only gives "elementor_canvas" and "elementor_header_footer" as options next to Wordpress defaults.

If I wanted to assign Elementor’s Full Width Page Template to a post, is there a way to do this via the Wordpress REST api or programmatically via a workaround?

```
    def create_page(title):
            post = {
            'title'    : title,
            'status'   : 'publish',
            'template' : 'elementor_canvas'
            }

            response = requests.post(url + '/pages', headers=header, json=post)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround involves creating an Elementor template then using the sortcode as the content of the post e.g.

```
def create_page(title):
        post = {
        'title'    : title,
        'status'   : 'publish',
        'content' : '[elementor-template id="1159"]'
        }
```